# browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting may not be overridden

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver for firefox on C# project. After I installed the latest webdriver (2.40) with NuGet Package manager this error occurred:

> The type initializer for 'Class' threw an exception. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Preference
>   browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting may not be overridden:
>   frozen value=False, requested value=False.

My code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

The error is raised on the second line.
Do you have any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: I think that particular property is blocked for editing with the new patch. I try to run my application without it and works. I also looked into firefox  config page about:config to see if the browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting option is there and indeed it is. The problem is the property is set to true and we cannot change it to false as I need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET bindings were recently updated to match the behavior of other language bindings, using a preset list of profile settings, some of which are not changeable if one expects the `FirefoxDriver` to work properly. The preference you're attempting to set is one of those "frozen" settings. It should already have the value you're attempting to set it to. If it doesn't, there may be a bug in the driver.

---

You can verify that the setting is already what you desire, but looking at the exception details:

**Example:**

```
profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
```

throws the error:

> System.ArgumentException: Preference network.http.phishy-userpass-length may not be overridden: frozen value=**255**, requested value=**255**

Meaning the frozen value would already be correct, and that `SetPreference()` can be removed.

Comment: Thank you, so is there a workaround to do this? Years ago I did bots with this functionality but now I cannot.