# Selenium webdriver C# Firefox auto save file error

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I made this with c# so that firefox save'd my file automatic without save as dialog box

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/x-msdownload");

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

but when i try to launch NUnit auto test it shows me error 
**showWhenStarting may not be overriden: frozen value= false, request value = false.**
Can any body help me? I tryed to delete this line but the it gives me another error...

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the *"frozen" preferences*, see:

- [browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting may not be overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930453/browser-download-manager-showwhenstarting-may-not-be-overridden)

As you can notice from the error, the value is already `false`:

```
frozen value= false, request value = false
```

You can safely remove this line:

```
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
```

Comment: @JaraSkuder well, now it's a different problem.

Comment: @JaraSkuder at least you need to set `browser.download.folderList`, `browser.download.dir` and make sure you have a correct mime-type value in `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`. As an example, see http://yizeng.me/2014/05/23/download-pdf-files-automatically-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver/.